# How do I see what tcp ports are allowed in from anywhere by my firewall?

Tags: ubuntu, tcp, port

How do I see what tcp ports are allowed in from anywhere by my firewall? (Ubuntu 16) . I'm trying to locate the ports that are allowed in from anywhere by my firewall, but can't seem to find them.

Comment: UFW can be useful in that i think. Take a look here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW

Answer (score 0):

You could use nmap for that.
For example to list all open ports of `8.8.8.8`:

```
root@psandro:~# nmap 8.8.8.8

Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-01-13 23:07 CET
Nmap scan report for google-public-dns-a.google.com (8.8.8.8)
Host is up (0.00081s latency).
Not shown: 998 filtered ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
53/tcp  open  domain
443/tcp open  https

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 4.66 seconds
```